# Where is the (OSX) path for an updated version of the Android NDK?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-ndk, installation

Where is the path for an updated version of the Android NDK?  I'm on Mac OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

I used android-ndk-r10e for a good while, but just updated to the latest version of the NDK using Android Studio's SDK Manager.  I watched its progress and noted that it was version r12 and also the root dir where it was installing, but when I went to look for it I can't find anything that looks like my original installation.

When I originally installed r10e, the folder name that it installed into was/is:

```
/android-ndk-r10e
```

Below is my CHANGELOG.md that I found in the ndk-bundle folder of the dir where the update seemed to be installed.  Seems clear that r12b was installed, but where? Shouldn't there be an "android-ndk-r12b" folder somewhere?

```
Changelog
=========

Report issues to [GitHub].

[GitHub]: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues

Announcements
-------------

 * `ndk-build` will default to using Clang in r13. GCC will be removed in a
   later release.
 * `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` will be removed in r13. Make sure
   `make_standalone_toolchain.py` suits your needs.

r12b
----

 * `ndk-gdb.py` has been fixed: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/118
 * NdkCameraMetadataTags.h has been updated to no longer contain the invalid
   enum value.
 * A bug in `ndk-build` that resulting in spurious warnings for static libraries
   using libc++ has been fixed:
   https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/238146/
 * The OpenSLES headers have been updated for android-24.

NDK
---
 * Removed support for the armeabi-v7a-hard ABI. See the explanation in the
   [documentation](docs/HardFloatAbi.md).
 * Removed all sysroots for pre-GB platform levels. We dropped support for them
   in r11, but neglected to actually remove them.
 * Exception handling when using `c++_shared` on ARM32 now mostly works (see
   [Known Issues](#known-issues)). The unwinder will now be linked into each
   linked object rather than into libc++ itself.
 * Default compiler flags have been pruned:
   https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/27.
     * Full changes here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/207721/5.
 * Added a Python implementation of standalone toolchains:
   `build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py`.
     * Windows users: you no longer need Cygwin to use this feature.
     * We'll be removing the bash flavor in r13, so test the new one now.
 * `-fno-limit-debug-info` has been enabled by default for Clang debug builds.
   This should improve debugability with LLDB.
 * `--build-id` is now enabled by default.
     * This will be shown in native crash reports so you can easily identify
       which version of your code was running.
 * `NDK_USE_CYGPATH` should no longer cause problems with libgcc:
   http://b.android.com/195486.
 * `-Wl,--warn-shared-textrel` and`-Wl,--fatal-warnings` are now enabled by
   default. If you have shared text relocations, your app will not load on
   Marshmallow or later (and have never been allowed for 64-bit apps).
 * Precompiled headers should work better:
   https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/14 and
   https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/16.
 * Unreachable ARM (non-thumb) STL libraries have been removed.
 * Added Vulkan support to android-24.
 * Added Choreographer API to android-24.
 * Added `libcamera2` APIs for devices with
   `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED` or above (see [Camera
   Characteristics]).

[Camera Characteristics]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL

Clang
-----

 * Clang has been updated to 3.8svn (r256229, build 2812033).
     * Note that Clang packaged in the Windows 64-bit NDK is actually 32-bit.
 * `__thread` should work for real this time.

GCC
---

 * Synchronized with the ChromeOS GCC @ `google/gcc-4_9` r227810.
 * Backported coverage sanitizer patch from ToT (r231296).
 * Fixed libatomic to not use ifuncs:
   https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/31.

Binutils
--------

 * "Erratum 843419 found and fixed" info messages are silenced.
 * Introduced option '--long-plt' to fix internal linker error when linking huge
   arm32 binaries.
 * Fixed wrong run time stubs for AArch64. This was causing jump addresses to be
   calculated incorrectly for very large DSOs.
 * Introduced default option '--no-apply-dynamic' to work around a dynamic
   linker bug for earlier Android releases.
 * NDK r11 KI for `dynamic_cast` not working with Clang, x86, `stlport_static`
   and optimization has been fixed.

GDB
---

 * Updated to GDB 7.11: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/.
 * Some bugfixes for `ndk-gdb.py`.

Known Issues
------------

 * This is not intended to be a comprehensive list of all outstanding bugs.
 * x86 ASAN still does not work. See discussion on
   https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/186276/
 * Exception unwinding with `c++_shared` still does not work for ARM on
   Gingerbread or Ice Cream Sandwich.
 * Bionic headers and libraries for Marshmallow and N are not yet exposed
   despite the presence of android-24. Those platforms are still the Lollipop
   headers and libraries (not a regression from r11).
 * RenderScript tools are not present (not a regression from r11):
   https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/7.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Answering my own question here.  Apparently the installation puts an "ndk-bundle" folder into your SDK installation folder when updating the ndk.  This is what you are supposed to reference in your Android Studio projects.  My updated path to the r12b version of the NDK now is as follows:

```
.../android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle
```

Comment: Did you have to accept licenses for **CMake** before building your NDK project?

Comment: I have not had to do that, no.